# Common UI for both Dektop and metro Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I need to develop common  UI which will run on both desktop and metro.

Is this possible.I wanted to use same code for UI both in desktop and metro app

I know that Win RT is Supported on both desktop and metro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is about creating an application that works like both Metro Style and also as a traditional desktop app. What you need to do is to wrap all your business logic code into a `WinRT DLL` and create two different UI applications one using `XAML` and another using `windows Form` and consume the DLL.

But ideally you cant have a single exe that runs like a native app and a metro style app, you should have two exe's.

Another thing is the native app which you develop in this manner may not be backward compatible because in `build` conference i remember them saying `WinRT` is only from `Windows 8` onwards. so you cant run your native app in `Windows 7`.

Comment: I guess XAML can also used in Desktop Version.

Comment: @Chris_vr: Yes you can use XAML in WPF